# Return Objects in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm trying to return an object from a function but I'm getting the error is there any way I can do that?

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Mutations;

final class Login
{
    /**
     * @param  null  $_
     * @param  array{}  $args
     */
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        
        return{
            ok: false,
            Error: "password not correct"
            token: "jhfkjnfknkfdj"
        };
}
```

Comment: *I'm getting the error* - it is generally better to include the actual error text which usually has important details.

Comment: That's not valid PHP code. You can't use JSON syntax in PHP like that.

Comment: so can you please tell me how i can do it?

Comment: The docs explains it well: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#json-responses

Comment: and how i can call that function in mutation

Comment: ` extend type Mutation {
    login(email:String! , password:String!):logingR!
}


type logingR{
    ok:Boolean!
    Error: String
    token: String
}`

Comment: You better master php basics before jumping to GraphQL stuff. It's hard to take it all at once.

Here's a good one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUCiSSyIGGU&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

Comment: i have experience with node js apollo graphql im just trying to implement javascript graphql in laravel PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use an array casted as an object:

```php
return (object)[
    'ok' => false,
    'Error' => "password not correct",
    'token' => "jhfkjnfknkfdj",
];
```

For Laravel:

```php
return response()->json([
    'ok' => false,
    'Error' => "password not correct",
    'token' => "jhfkjnfknkfdj",
]);
```

Comment: and how i can get that res via mutation

Comment: `
type logingR{
    ok:Boolean
    Error: String
    token: String
}

extend type Mutation {
    login(email:String! , password:String!): logingR!
}
`